# encrypt a string to obtain a fixed length

Tags: python, django, url, encoding, compression

let's suppose I have the following possible values of a string:

```
exp="110"
exp="110-120"
exp="110-120-211"
```

actually, this is a GET parameter obtained from the URL. `exp` can become very large so I want to make it shorter(encrypt it). Not because of security reasons, but because I don't want it to be long and ugly.

So I want to encrypt `exp` to become a short string with a fixed length of let's say 15. Is it possible somehow? Something like this:

```
encrypt("110")     results in "Ax1234B"
encrypt("110-120") results in "85xHdjX"
```

I am using python btw

**EDIT**

forgot to mention: I also need a `decrypt` function to be available. Moreover, I would prefer solutions from the standard python library without having to install new packages.

Comment: nope, its not possible to fit an arbitrarily large set of data into a fix length in a reversible way.  maybe you need to redefine whats allowed.  You can certainly shorten it though

Comment: One approach we have used to shorten is to zip the string then base64 encode it.  This obviously is not fix length, but is very reversible.

Comment: What is the domain of the data you are trying to communicate?

Comment: If you want to make something smaller and if you don't have any security requirements then you are talking about compression. If you want to store the compressed form in a specific string you are talking about encoding. If you don't mind I change the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

How long are your strings getting? If they're sufficiently long, you could compress them using `zlib` (or another compression module in the standard libary) and then run base64 on it.

```
>>> z = base64.encodestring(zlib.compress("123"))
>>> print z 
eJwzNDIGAAEtAJc=
>>> zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring(z)) 
'123'
```

This isn't going to shrink your strings unless they're pretty long, though (in my tests about 36 characters in the original string). You're also not getting a fixed length, but I don't believe there's any way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert urls into a fixed length strings; you could use a hash function and a database to be able to retrieve the url given its hash:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('urls.sqlite3')
db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls
              (hash BLOB PRIMARY KEY, url TEXT)''')

def shorten(url):
    h = sqlite3.Binary(hashlib.sha256(url.encode('ascii')).digest())
    with db:
        db.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO urls VALUES (?, ?)', (h, url))
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(h).decode('ascii')

def geturl(shortened_url):
    h = sqlite3.Binary(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(shortened_url.encode('ascii')))
    with db:
        url = db.execute('SELECT url FROM urls WHERE hash=?', (h,)).fetchone()
    if url is None:
        raise KeyError(shortened_url)
    return url[0]
```

#### Example

```
urls = ["110", "110-120", "110-120-211"]
width = max(map(len, urls))
for url in urls:
    slug = shorten(url)
    assert url == geturl(slug)
    print('{url:{width}} -> {slug}'.format(**vars()))
```

#### Output

```
110         -> m9sq9nmSBKKZxgOZS45ADksf1iXv23QGbMhp_uQsnfM=
110-120     -> aKGvjidWggSkQ1wBnZoi5f67KlUS1pvoVyhX8Rd04P0=
110-120-211 -> C8LD7lCh5Tm8XCoWJep9OAfSnMikLU5lgQChe-wfQho=
```

The output always has the same length however long (or short) input urls are.

For a sufficiently long hash with a good algorithm the probability of collision (different urls producing the same hash) is very low for any practical number of url hashes generated.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote but what is the reason for it? How the answer could be improved?

Comment: My guess is that this does not work, as you mention yourself, when collision happens. Who wants to rely on something that MAY not break, but when first collision actually happens, the solution will not work?

Comment: @StephanRyer I might have understated how low the probability is in practice. In any case, it is easy to detect the collision and provide a workaround depending on a specific task.

Comment: The propability increases the more strings you want to encrypt, so without knowing this number - it is not actually possible to say anything about the overall chance for this to happen.

Comment: @StephanRyer the number of possible sha256 hashes: `2**256` Age of the Universe in seconds is tiny tiny by comparison: `~10**21`. You can generate billions hashes per second every second of the Universe existence and you use only tiny tiny part of all possible hashes¶ Given that the solution uses a DB, if we detect the very unlikely collision (just remove 'OR IGNORE' in the code), we could use a random free hash instead among many many possible candidates.

Answer (score 0):

If security is not an issue at all and you only want to obfuscate and shrink, maybe use [base64](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html)?  It's implemented in both Javascript and Python, so you can easily encode it on the frontend and decode it on the backend.

However, this will not get you a fixed length, unless you deliberately pad up to a certain length larger the actual length.

Comment: base64 by itself actually grows strings

Comment: yes, I was thinking about base64, but as my string grows in length, also the base64 grows. I thought there might be another solution..

Comment: @cmd Hmm, that's right; I guess it would be possible to convert the data represented by the string (which seems to be numbers and dashes) to binary and then encode it in base64 but that seems like an awful lot of trouble.

Comment: @MihaiZamfir You can make a representation larger up to a fixed limit, but you can't make it smaller down to a fixed limit without losing data.  Of course, there is actual compression, but I don't know of many compression techniques that will work on super tiny strings.

Comment: For what it's worth, arcane and ugly query strings in URLs are just a fact of life for most major websites.  See for instance Youtube, Amazon, Google...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, its not possible to fit an arbitrarily large set of data into a fix length in a reversible way. You need to define what is being passed a little better.

For example if:

- From your examples it looks like a list of numbers.
- The numbers are relatively small.
- Duplicates not permitted

If these are true you could pack your list as bits into a single binary stream of fixed size up to the maxium number of bits as the max number and then base64 encode it.  This would be fixed length and reversible.